# How can I delete all network users on startup or shutdown?

Tags: user-account, startup, shutdown, macos

I want to run this script before any student logs into the computers daily.

```
#!/bin/sh

mv /Users/admin /admin

wait $pid

mv /Users/Shared /Shared

wait $pid

rm -rf /Users/*

wait $pid

mv /admin /Users/admin

wait $pid

mv /Shared /Users/Shared

wait $pid
```

I want to keep the "admin" and "Shared" and delete the rest. I don't want to do it while students are using the computers. On start up or shutdown would be the best idea. Can I automate this?

Comment: hre are some ideas https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/23407/script-to-delete-users-and-home-folders-but-not-admin-accounts